# IdentityServer3 with external user management

Tags: authentication, authorization, thinktecture-ident-server, thinktecture

Given a scenario where a web hosted IdentityServer3 *only handles **authorization***, being user authentication handled by an external custom service, what is required to implement to support this? A custom OWIN middleware?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either connect to your "external custom service" form within your IUserService (idsrv specific) - or treat it as an external identity provider. In that case you need to write a Katana authentication middleware for it (reusable Katana component).

For the UserService check the IdentityServer docs. For Katana authentication middleware - not sure if there is official documentation for that - I covered that briefly it in my Web API security course.

http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/webapi-v2-security

Comment: Why would you choose one or the other? Could you enhance your answer with this information and implementation guides for both?

Comment: posted a new question based on your answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30485401/substitute-identityserver3-login-system)