# Substitute IdentityServer3 login system

Tags: authentication, thinktecture-ident-server, identityserver3, thinktecture

Following @leastprivilege answer in my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30357744/identityserver3-with-external-user-management), I concluded that neither are possible solutions:

- The login service doesn't support REST authentication (thus, can't use `IUserService.AuthenticateLocalAsync` and just connect to it)
- I don't need it to be an additional provider, I need it to substitute IS3 one, ie, instead of showing the local login + additional providers, I need the /login page to be the one from a different service.

Can this be customized or do I need to change IdentityService3 source? If so, what to I need to guarantee implementation wise in order for to achieve the authentication and not break the authorization?

UPDATE

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29999406/859738) the solution might be creating a new provider and setting the automatic redirect somewhere using `acr_values`

Comment: So how do you connect then to your login service from within the the katana module. Not sure I understand the REST comment. In general I would recommend using the github issue tracker instead. I don't monitor SO.

Comment: @leastprivilege I haven't implemented the katana middleware, didn't find any proper documentation on the matter and thought it could be done in different ways (which all failed so, back to that now).

Comment: @leastprivilege Regarding the REST part, instead of opening the external login page, I was going for a UserService with a local authentication, doing a call with the credentials to that page, just for POC purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it after some research. You'll need this three steps:

- A Owin Authentication middleware that redirects to the page you want, providing the protected state (this will let you finish the authentication process later). You can follow [Anders Abel tutorial]
- Custom user service that overrides the `PreAuthentication` method and sets the `SignInMessage message.Idp` with your middleware id. Code sample: [check it here](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/blob/master/source/CustomHrd/CustomHrd/HrdUserService.cs)
- After the successful authentication, your page should redirect to the middleware callback with the state parameter. With the mentioned dummy middleware, it's set as `/signing-dummy`